# Where is Model class inheriting its create method for mass assignment?

Tags: php, laravel

I know this is probably a really beginner's question and it most definitly stems from my inexperience in PHP. So don't hate me SO.

I've been learning Laravel for the last weeks. In their docs for mass assignment they talk about the `create` method. As per their example -

`$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);`

Yet as much as I try to search in the API docs or the source, I can't seem to find the method its referencing, at least not in the `Model` class. The only plausible thing I found was a method from the `Builder` class in Eloquent.

I'm not expecting anyone to search through the docs for me. I'm much more interested in knowing what would be the best practice to find the inheritance chain for the particular method and log it or dump it.

Comment: wich editor / ide do you use? i recommend you put https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper <- this file in your project, it shows a lot of hidden inheritance chains that normally you can't access, and try extending the Eloquent  class on your model instead of the Model class

Comment: @PedroFaria99 I'm actually using phpstorm with laravel-ide-helper already. If it's supposed to show off that hidden inheritance I dunno how to do it. And btw, how could you achieve that hidden inheritance anyhow?

Comment: you can ctrl click the function in the ide

Comment: @PedroFaria99 Thx! Seems it was `Builder` after all. Anyway this actually raises even more questions for me. How can the `Model` class even access it?

Comment: Because Model is an abstract class, wich is extended by Eloquent, so PHPStorm has trouble finding the origin, the ide-helper does just that.

Comment: @PedroFaria99 Like I said, I knew this misunderstanding had to be related with my lack of knowledge of how PHP works. Actually I was just relying on Laravel's docs to understand this. Still, could you touch on the subject of how do I try to log the inheritance chain for a function or the likes? Cos next time I might not have this problem with Laravel.

Comment: check the last answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880862/can-one-output-the-full-inheritance-chain-of-a-class-in-php, i think it's exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create()` method is located in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L754

You can find it by looking at `Model::__callStatic()` → `__call()`.
These are magic methods (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

Answer (score 0):

It is coming from the `Builder` class. You can see the code here:

```
/**
 * Save a new model and return the instance. Allow mass-assignment.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|$this
 */
public function forceCreate(array $attributes)
{
    return $this->model->unguarded(function () use ($attributes) {
        return $this->newModelInstance()->create($attributes);
    });
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L754